# Would you trust this PVC drain joint?

Tags: drain, drain-waste-vent, pvc

[image: PVC joint with clear fitting - dark areas show glue seal]

This is a joint for a 2" elbow underneath a unit-shower (in Japan.) The elbow is a special type which is clear, and using a blue glue shows the glue line so you can insure you have a good joint. An example of a good seal can be seen at this link -- [Fitting mfg. product page](http://www.kubota-ci.co.jp/products/building/dv/whatsnew.html)

My guess is that the shower manufacturer requires the contractor to use this type of fitting because the joint is impossible to repair once the shower room is installed and assembled. The contractor was crappy, and I threw him off the job, but now I see that the plumber he used may have been questionable also.

From the photo, you can see the glue seal on the bottom half of the pipe (the photo is rotated so to the right is the slab, and to the left is the underside of the shower floor.) There also appears to be a thin line of blue at the very end of the pipe, so my guess is it does not leak. The silvery patches mean there is an air gap between fitting and pipe.

There is no seal at on the top half, and even the bottom half looks sketchy. I plan a leak test on Monday, but my real concern is that with future stress (temblors, temperature, age,) the thin line will crack and water will forever seep out.

So, does anyone know if this would be considered a satisfactory PVC joint? I can find very little on the web, I think mostly because this type of fitting is not too common, but what I do see says that with such poor coverage the joint needs to be redone.

To redo it, I need to disassemble the shower (several says of work) but I have not built adjoining walls and floors so I want to do it now if it needs to be done.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: not that it helps you now, but FYI, when you can, it's best to put an access panel on the reverse side of the shower fixtures for this very purpose. That's not always doable depending on the layout and orientation, but when you can, it's nice to be able to orient the shower fixtures towards an interior closet wall so you can later access it from the other side if need be.

Comment: I was really surprised that the design does not allow access. This is a standard product in Japan, called a "unit bath," and basically is a complete room including tub, shower, floor, ceiling and walls, designed to sit on a slab with drain in the center so unless they add a panel in the floor, you have to dissemble to fix this.